# sql insert if exist and insert if not

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

If I already have data in my table 'current_schedule' with given date, I need to get that 'id' and INSERT into another table 'statistic' with that 'id'. If I haven't I need to create it and then INSERT with created 'id'. I almost done it :

```
   cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM current_schedule WHERE date = '{}'".format(lessondate))
    idforme = cursor.fetchone()
    if cursor.fetchone():
        idforme = idforme[0]
        if flag == str_to_bool('true'):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}','{}',1)".format(id_student,idforme))
        if flag == str_to_bool('false'):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}','{}',0)".format(id_student,idforme))
    else:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO current_schedule (id_schedule, date) VALUES ('{}','{}')".format(id_schedule,lessondate))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        if flag == str_to_bool('true'):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}',LAST_INSERT_ID(),1)".format(id_student))
        if flag == str_to_bool('false'):
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                    VALUES ('{}',LAST_INSERT_ID(),0)".format(id_student))
    mysql.connection.commit()
```

But the problem is what it creates the new one data twice in 'current_schedule' and only after that in starts to insert data with already created 'id' (first one) into 'statistic'.

Comment: Are you certain `flag` is only ever `'true'` or `'false'`? Could you try putting `else` instead of `if flag == str_to_bool('false'):` and see if something gets created in `statistic` at the first attempt?

Comment: @Nick I already solve it by adding in first if condition 'idforme' instead of cursor.fetchone

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this since it's largely the same query:

```
else:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO current_schedule (id_schedule, date) VALUES ('{}','{}')".format(id_schedule,lessondate))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    flagNum = 0 if flag == str_to_bool('false') else 1
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO statistic (id_student, id_current_schedule,here) \
                VALUES ('{}',LAST_INSERT_ID(),{})".format(id_student, flagNum))
    mysql.connection.commit()
```